# How to remove the mail built-in icon from content_main

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to remove the mail icon.

I can't find any way to do it.
Below is the default icon that i see when i start a 'Blank Activity' on the Android Studio

screenshot attached [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `activity_main.xml` you have a layout like this:

[image]

You can:

- remove the **FloatingActionButton** (also in the MainActivity!)
- change the entire layout

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity Class, remove the below code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```